# Prime Number generator from 2 to 100 in r

Tags: r

Can someone help me and show me the reason why my prime number generator doesn't work?:

```
d=0
primeno<- c(2:100)
for(i in primeno)
{
     for(j in 1:i)
      {
           if(j %% i == 0)
           d=d+1
      }
  if(d==2)
  print ("Prime")
  d=0
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit the question to indicate what output you are getting, and any error messages - 'it's not working' isn't enough information to help the community assist you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Only inverts the indexes `(j %% i)` for `(i %% j)`, the number is the index "i" and divisor is the index "j".

```
d=0
primeno<- c(2:100)
for(i in primeno)
{
  for(j in 1:i)
  {
    if(i %% j == 0)
      d=d+1
  }
  if(d==2)
    cat(i,"- Prime \n")
  d=0
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to *explain* what's wrong ...

Comment: can you edit your answer to include that?

Answer (score 0):

Now, this works:

```
d=0
primeno<- c(2:100)

for(i in 2:length(primeno)){

  for(j in 1:i){
    if(i %% j == 0){
      d=d+1
    }
  }

if(d==2){
  print(i)
  print ("Prime")
  }

d <- 0

}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to *explain* what's wrong ...